# How to Set Terminal Services User Preferences?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-terminal-services, user-profile, user-settings, preferences

The server that hosts my terminal service is set to use `dd/mm/yyyy` and `Pounds` for currency. When I login as a user instead of getting the aforementioned settings I get `mm/dd/yyyy` and `Dollars` for currency; however, if I login as an administrator, the expected setting are used. Does anyone know what to do in order to have non-administrator users get the desired settings of dd/mm/yyyy and Pounds? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regional and currency settings are [part of the user profile](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/registry2/jsi-tip-0311-regional-settings-in-the-registry-), so it is a per-user setting. If you want to set it for everybody, you should consider using group policies in conjunction with either a [custom-written ADM file](http://www.robertoalves.com/2008/adm-with-regional-settings-using-british-as-default/) or using [Group Policy Preferences](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731892.aspx) if you have a Windows Server 2008 or Vista management station to deploy the necessary management snapins on.

Comment: Thanks for the links; they've been very helpful. I followed your suggestion of using a custom ADM file. I put together an ADM file using the links you provided. While I was able to successfully add my ADM file to the 'administrative templates' and enable the policy configurations, the policies (i.e. datetime & currency settings) did NOT take effect. Do you have any idea why the the policies enabled via the ADM file are NOT taking effect? Thanks.

Comment: you can use either gpresult or [rsop.msc](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323276) on your terminal server to see if your policy has been applied to the specific user session. Following a good practice, you should separate your regional settings into an own policy - this also would facilitate debugging. If the policy *has* been applied but the registry values are still incorrect, there might be another conflicting policy or a logon script re-setting these values.

Answer (score 0):

You could merge a .reg file with the relevant settings at login as well. Its not a clean as using an ADM file though but its a lot simpler

Answer (score 0):

In the Regional and Language Options on the Advanced tab there's a checkbox to apply all of the settings to the current user account and the default user profile. If you set the appropriate options and check this box then all new profiles created from the Default user profile will inherit these settings.

This won't change any existing user profiles but should ensure that all new user profiles inherit the correct settings.